# Find the smallest $p ∈ \mathbb{N}$ such that $A^p$ has no zero entries using Matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab

My Question is:

$Let A=\begin{pmatrix} 
  0&−1& 0& 1& 0& 0\\ 
  −1& 1& 0 &−1& 0& 0 \\
0&0 &0 &0& 1& 0\\
0 &1 &−1& 0 &0 &0\\
0& 0& −1& 0& −1& 1\\
0 &0 &0 &−1 &1 &0
\\
\end{pmatrix}$

By using Matlab, find the smallest $p ∈ \mathbb{N}$ such that $A^p$ has no zero entries.

I know I can use trial and error to eventually get to my answer, but is their a script that could get to my answer easier. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If the requirement is "using matlab", then how is this a math problem?

Comment: How do you know there is such a power?

Comment: Well there are question on this website dedicated to Matlab so I have no reason not to post this. @mathguy

Comment: We have been told there is a power but we just need to find it. @DonAntonio

Comment: @OPFragster You have a point, yet I think chances are you'll get more help  in the other section...I honestly don't understand how come that tag exists here, in the mathematics section...

Comment: Without knowing matlab: Can you compute the product of the elements of $A^p$? Then you need $\min \{p \mid \text{that product is not } 0\}$.

Comment: Im also confused as to why that tags here but its worth a go anyway @DonAntonio